# Passing Security Group Ids and Subnet Ids in a Clould Formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

```
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Type: String
  ClusterVersion:
    Type: Number
    AllowedValues: [1.21, 1.20, 1.19, 1.18]
  RoleArnValue:
    Type: String
  ListOfSubnetIDs: 
    Description: Array of Subnet IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  ListOfSecurityGroupIDs:
    Description: Array of security group ids
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>


Resources:
  EKSCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${ClusterName}
      Version: !Sub ${ClusterVersion}
      RoleArn: !Sub ${RoleArnValue}
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !Sub ${ListOfSecurityGroupIDs}
        SubnetIds:
          - !Sub ${ListOfSubnetIDs}
```

**Above is the .yaml clouldformation** template I have created so i can spin up eks cluster. Then i am using aws cli to spin up the cluster using the following command.

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file eks.yaml --stack-name cluster-test --parameter-overrides ClusterName=Dev ClusterVersion=1.21 ListOfSubnetIDs=subnet-11111d11b11b011f4,subnet-99999d237f87f11d7,subnet-222222c110c7e4be7,subnet-88888884de8d25176  ListOfSecurityGroupIDs=sg-01111111a21221 RoleArnValue=arn:aws:iam::123456546456:role/cluster-ServiceRole-WMIC72AOWSP0 --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

**I get the following error**

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: variable ListOfSecurityGroupIDs in Fn::Sub expression does not resolve to a string
```

I am not sure why. Am i using !sub in correctly? Would really appreciate input on this.

Comment: You need to use `!Ref`, not `!Sub`

Comment: oh is that the only change? And i guess if i am using !Ref i need to drop the "{" and "}". let me try that now

Comment: Did not worK i got this error Properties validation failed for resource EKSCluster with message: #/ResourcesVpcConfig/SecurityGroupIds/0: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/ResourcesVpcConfig/SecurityGroupIds/0: expected type: String, found: JSONArray #/ResourcesVpcConfig/SubnetIds/0: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/ResourcesVpcConfig/SubnetIds/0: expected type: String, found: JSONArray @Paolo

Comment: but for this to work wouldn't i have to change my parameter type to String? which beats the purpose of adding the List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id> type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to reference the parameters you provided the template as they are, you should use the `Ref` function.

Here's an example of a valid template:

```
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Type: String
  RoleArnValue:
    Type: String
  ListOfSubnetIDs: 
    Description: Array of Subnet IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  ListOfSecurityGroupIDs:
    Description: Array of security group ids
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>


Resources:
  EKSCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref ClusterName
      RoleArn: !Ref RoleArnValue
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref ListOfSecurityGroupIDs
        SubnetIds: !Ref ListOfSubnetIDs
```

and here's how I deployed it:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file eks.yml --stack-name cluster-test --parameter-overrides ClusterName=Dev ListOfSubnetIDs=subnet-be0a99c4,subnet-c71046ae ListOfSecurityGroupIDs=sg-009690ac6b3bff6df,sg-009a3f1cb63943941 -RoleArnValue=...
```

`Sub` should be used when you want to perform string manipulation. Checkout the examples from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html).